# Facebook Timeline : Add customized Facebook App to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

I have a Facebook App & a Facebook Page (with Facebook Timeline enabled).

The goal is to add the Facebook App to Facebook Page's boxes. I was able to achieve this one month ago using "[Add Page Tab Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/add_to_page/)" as told by Facebook Developers documentation, but I try the same thing today. It didn't work.

After I use the "Add Page Tab Dialog" :

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID
&display=popup&next=APPS_SECURE_CANVAS_URL
```

It shows up the dialog and I select my page. Last, after I click "Add Page Tab", it forwards to "APPS_SECURE_CANVAS_URL". But when I navigate back to my Page's URL, my Facebook App is still missing from the page.

What did I miss ? or Facebook is changing things now ?

Current Settings

```
Enabled : Apps on Facebook
Canvas URL : (empty)
Secure Empty URL : APPS_SECURE_CANVAS_URL

Enabled : Page Tab
Page Tab Name : My App Tab Name
Page Tab URL : (empty)
Secure Page Tab URL : APPS_SECURE_CANVAS_URL
Page Tab Edit URL : (empty)
Page Tab Width : Wide (810px)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

`Canvas URL` and `Page Tab URL` must be filled in, even it is started with HTTPS.

After these fields filled in, the "Add Page Tab Dialog" direct link works with any `next` URL under the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

So I am assuming you can't see the app in the drop down section either?

Go to edit your page. Click apps, edit the settings on your app and you will be able to add the tab and change other details.

Most likely you have added the application to your page before, you removed the tab but not the app and hence just need to re-add the tab.

Comment: I clicked `Manage > Edit page` > `Apps` > I only see "Photos", "Events", "Notes" and "Video", but not my application

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it should work. To solve that issue you can add the following snippet to your fangate. Don't forget to replace the `FB_APP_ID` and `FB_APP_CANVAS_URL` placeholder with your data.

```
<a href="#" onclick=window.open("http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=FB_APP_ID&redirect_uri=FB_APP_CANVAS_URL","PageTab","width=500,height=200");>
    ADD
</a>
```

Comment: this does not help too. still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://facebook.com in the place of APPS_SECURE_CANVAS_URL. It works for me.

Comment: This will lead to API Error Code: 191, API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application,
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.

Comment: No. The error is generated for all other urls. But facebook.com works. Did you actually try it?